# Truncation error on ADO insert command

Tags: c#, ado.net, truncate

I have a `foreach` loop run for every record in my list. When I execute it the it reaches the `ExecuteNonQuery()` and it throws this error:

String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

I have checked to make sure the field can hold my values an it can aka `varchar(10)` for L_Number
Now the S_O_Number is just int. Could this be the issue?

Here is my method that I run that is causing the truncation error.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dropdeadGridView.Rows)
 {
     bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells[5].Value);
     if (checkBoxValue)
     {
         o.Add(dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
     }
 }

 foreach (string num in o)
 {
     SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();
     try
     {
         using (dbConn)
         {
             SqlCommand addJob = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE OrderDetail SET L_NUMBER = @L_NUMBER WHERE S_O_NUMBER = @SONumber", dbConn);
             addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONumber", num);
             addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_NUMBER", lNumber.Text);
             dbConn.Open();
             addJob.ExecuteNonQuery();//error thrown
         }
         MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

throw ex;
     }
```

What happens above is it gets the values from my gridview based of checkbox selection. Puts them into a list. Which then I run a foreach loop to run for every value in the list. Why am I getting a truncation error when the data fits the size of the field?

Comment: Have you checked BOTH fields? `num` and `lNumber.Text`?

Comment: @jgauffin it is the primary key it just says int. I had no problems when I did this in WebForms with it. Is it just being in the problem?

Comment: @jgauffin I am updating the S_O_Number is int and the L_Number is varchar(10);

Comment: It might be int in the database, but in the above code it's a string. Check so it haven't been padded or similar.

Comment: Make sure you trim the text field.

Comment: @jgauffin for the DB table S_O_Number is the Primary Key. Then L_Number is what I am updating. S_O_Number is int and L_Number is varchar(10) in the db.

Comment: @jgauffin alright so L_Number is fine since it is varchar. Which means It must be num but when I convert num to int32 I still receive error.

Comment: This should be very simple to check by using a break point. Just check the real length of the two fields

Comment: @jgauffin it wasn't the fields it was a bad naming convention had the wrong field. Thank you for your help!